# Source files not created when creating a new Maven Project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've been going through some questions about this problem but I cant seem to get it right. I updated IntelliJ to Version to IntelliJ 2017.1.2. Before the upgrade it created these folders. Now when I create a project I select Maven-archetype quick start. I enter the project name etc. it creates the project. But the only folder I see there is .idea. No source directory then main etc. How can I get these folders? Can I just create the folders myself?

Does it have anything to with the pom.xml?

Comment: Which archetype are you selecting?

Comment: maven-archetype-quickstart

Comment: I think that this is an introduced bug. Newer versions of Maven do not interpolate versions such as `LATEST` or `RELEASE`. If you pick an archetype with a real version it may work.

Comment: this is all I am getting in the POM.xml                                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Test3</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>

Comment: What I did now is reinstalled IntelliJ Idea 2017.1.2 and Selected the option not to import previous version settings.